# Mid 1980's book or series: hacker augmented with injected nano-chips

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a book or series in the mid 1980's which featured:

- organic computers that had to be connected to a tap by the hacker so that the running water would cool them
- main character(s) injected with nano-chips (as children?) that gave them special (mental?) abilities
- high-tech spy gear included a cool-suit which absorbed body heat to elude thermal imaging cameras around the yard of a building, but had a limited usability because after a certain amount of time the heat-sinks would have to vent steam or else quickly cook the wearer.

Unsure if within the same series, but there was one character who stowed away on a spaceship which was travelling to one of the gas-giant planets in our Solar System (Jupiter or Saturn?) and within the gas giant whale-like intelligences were discovered.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer regarding the book with the spy-gear, but I might have a match for the other one.

[This review](http://www.concatenation.org/frev/wellofstars.html) of [Robert Reed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Reed_(author))'s [The Well of Stars](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/100327.The_Well_of_Stars) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Well_of_Stars)) talks about:

> the whale-like creatures of a gas giant's moon who come together emitting radio waves to sing to the gas giant's own, natural, electromagnetic radio broadcast as these marine aliens think the gas giant is a god speaking to them.

and describes the main characters as

> human stowaway commanders ... now in charge and gallivanting around the Galaxy.

Not sure how good a match this is - I suspect the stowing away would have to have been in its prequel, [Marrow](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/100208.Marrow), and to be honest it seems that the human crew would only be stowaways from the POV of the ship's missing alien crew (if it ever had one!)

Comment: Thanks @Astrid_Redfern. The whale-like creature reference was very hopeful. The rest of the summaries suggest a story unfamiliar to me. My search continues...